# WebRTC to render H.264 video streams

Tags: html, udp, h.264, webrtc

I am developing a web application where I need to integrate H.264 UDP Streams. I am currently using HTML5. I want to know if I can do the same using WebRTC before I proceed.

Comment: Could you please explain what 'integrate H.264 UDP Streams' is? Do you mean RTP streams?

Comment: It is just bare UDP and no RTP. I want to display these UDP streams in the browser using HTML5. Can WebRTC be one of the solutions?

Comment: sadly the top hit for the google search "webrtc udp h264 stream" is this question. Any progress @user3392740?

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC has lots of code related to h.264 decoding and rendering (i.e. [here](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/80bc1acb9c2b9d8096f356c748ec9b57e02759c9/sdk/objc/components/video_codec/RTCVideoDecoderH264.mm) is WebRTC calling Mac APIs).

However, WebRTC is a monolithic piece of code, in that the networking and decoding are tied together. I don't believe you can build your own networking component, and then give the h.264 stream to WebRTC to decode and render.